# How to speed up or vectorize your process in your Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple `shiny` App which has an upload button in the side Panel and in the main panel there are **four value  box** to represents

- total number of sheets.
- total number of sheets with empty  data.
- total number of sheets  with character values in particular column

Here there's a loop which goes through every sheet.

The Excel file has **543** sheets with rows ranges from **1000 - 6000**. So the generation of values in the box becomes a slow process. I wanted speed it up. How can I achieve this.
Do I need to use other languages or is there any other method. .

[Sample Excel File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/sv2y7zak6uc2e0mbqcp4t/Sample.xlsx?rlkey=6ltfybldtd5v4umiszh8m0272&dl=0)

Sample Shiny App

```
# install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("deepanshu88/summaryBox")
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(bsplus)
library(summaryBox)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sample"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("upload", "Upload an Excel File", accept = c(".xlsx", ".csv"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        type = "tabs", id = "tabs-nav",
        tabPanel("Sheet Info", 
                 uiOutput(outputId = "summarybox")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Upload file Size Limit (100mb)
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 200 * 1024^2)
  
  # Stop R sesson after closing of the App
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
  
  output$summarybox <- renderUI({
    
    req(input$upload)
    sheets_all <- readxl::excel_sheets(input$upload$datapath)
    
    sheets_clean <- list()
    sheets_empty <- list()
    sheets_text <- list()
    
    for (sheet_name in sheets_all) {
      
      if (sheet_name != "Metadata") {
        data <- readxl::read_xlsx(input$upload$datapath, sheet = sheet_name)
        
        # Skip if sheet is empty
        if (nrow(data) == 0) {
          sheets_empty <- append(sheets_empty, sheet_name)
          next
        }
        
        # Check if the 3rd column contains character values
        if (is.character(data[[3]])) {
          sheets_text <- append(sheets_text, sheet_name)
          next
        }
        
        sheets_clean <- append(sheets_clean, sheet_name)
      }
    }
    
    nrows_clean <- length(sheets_clean)
    nrows_empty <- length(sheets_empty)
    nrows_text <- length(sheets_text)
    total_sheets <- length(sheets_text) + length(sheets_empty) + length(sheets_clean)
    
    fluidRow(
      summaryBox2("Clean Sheets", nrows_clean , width = 3, icon = "fa-solid fa-circle-check", style = "success"),
      summaryBox2("Empty Sheets", nrows_empty, width = 3, icon = "fa-solid fa-exclamation", style = "danger"),
      summaryBox2("Text Sheets", nrows_text, width = 3, icon = "fa-solid fa-exclamation", style = "info"),
      summaryBox2("Total Sheets", total_sheets  , width = 3, icon = "fa-solid fa-exclamation", style = "primary")
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Don't grow your lists inside a `for` loop.  Use a member of the `apply` family to construct the lists for you.  Refactor your code so that you read in all your data, then calculate statistics.  Investigate whether the overhead of parallelising your code is worthwhile in your particular use case.  [`mclapply` is an obvious and simple option.] Provide a reproducible example so that others can test their suggestions if they wish.

Comment: Giving 500 sheet of excel file is not possible right now.

Comment: I realise that. But you can establish the principle with only two or three. Help yourself by helping others to help you.

Comment: Okay. Ill add that sample Excel file.

Comment: @Limey. I have added one sample Excel file

Answer (score 1):

I think it is wise to test such parsing outside your Shiny app, also this question is not Shiny related. It would also make it better for asking on Stackoverflow that way, not obscured by other code not related to your question. It makes it easier also to do speed tests and perhaps you can try different xlsx libraries to see if some do the job faster. Anyhow I stick to the `readxl` as in your code. Not sure if this would be fast enough for you, but at least we get rid of the loops.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

sheets <- path_to_file %>% 
  excel_sheets() %>%
  map(read_excel, path = path_to_file)

checks <- colSums(do.call(rbind, (lapply(sheets, \(x) {
  c(
    "sheets_empty" = nrow(x) == 0,
    "sheets_text" = ifelse(ncol(x) >=3, is.character(x[[3]]), FALSE)
  )
}))))
  
total_sheets <- length(sheets)
nrows_empty  <- checks[["sheets_empty"]]
nrows_text <- checks[["sheets_text"]]
nrows_clean <- total_sheets - nrows_empty - nrows_text
```

Comment: I did benchmark this method its faster by 12 sec than the for loop